# A $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $I(X) \neq I(V(I(X)))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{A}^n$ be the affine $n$-space over a field $K$. Denote by $V(S)$ the zero locus of a $S \subseteq K[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and let $I(X)$ be the ideal of a $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$. Is there any $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ such that $I(X) \neq I(V(I(X)))$? If yes, give an example, please.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection

Comment: No such an $X$ does not exist. This question should be reopened: the accepted answer assumes that the base field is algebraically closed, which is not necessary,  and uses the Nullstellensatz which is overkill  and actually obscures the trivial and purely formal reason why $I(V(I(X))=I(X)$ for any subset $X\subset \mathbb A^n$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I get more or less your point. However there is absolutely no effort shown from OP and so I don't see any good reason to reopen the question.

Comment: I evoked this question on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/why-was-this-question-put-on-hold)

Comment: @Surb This is a question a friend of mine asked me to do: He's a PhD student in a nearby mathematics university but as he had no internet at the moment, he asked me to ask this for him via SMS, as I explained in the comment to the user who provided an answer. My friend told me that no additional motivation was needed and that he had a personal style of asking *dry* questions.

Comment: @Surb Notice that the level of this question is far beyond my usual questions. The answer provider even spoke about [Hilbert's Nutella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutella). Must be very profound indeed.

Comment: @Voyska I'm definitely not a "question closing fan" and I think often that some questions are closed for no good reason. But I think that **this** question is very badly asked: what is $\mathbb{A}^n$? what are $I$ and $V$?
I mean even if I would like to, just with the question in its actual state, I'd have no way to understand it. Googling A,I or V will not bring me anywhere...

Comment: @Surb My friend said that in the context of algebraic geometry, anyone who had studied it would understand.

Comment: The inclusion $J\subset I(V(J))$ is a tautology valid for any ideal $J\subset k[T_1,\cdots, T_n]$. Putting  $J=I(X)$ you get $I(X) \subset I(V(I(X))$. Similarly $X\subset V(I(X))$ is a tautology and since the operator $I$ reverses inclusion you get $I(X)\supset I(V(I(X)))$. The two inclusions I have proved imply the required equality $I(X)= I(V(I(X)))$. The above essentially trivial proof does not require $k$ to be algebraically  closed  and there is certainly no need to invoke a hard theorem like Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @Voyska thank you for editing the question: I changed my $-1$ into a $+1$ :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (with Georges Elencwajg's Suggestion):  We assume that $K$ is a commutative integral ring (not necessarily unital).  Let $S$ be an ideal of $K\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right]$ and $X\subseteq K\mathbb{A}^n$.  We claim that $\sqrt{I(X)}=I(X)=I\Big(V\big(I(X)\big)\Big)$ and that $V\big(\sqrt{S}\big)=V(S)=V\Big(I\big(V(S)\big)\Big)$.  We invoke five properties:

(1) $Y\subseteq V\big(I(Y)\big)$ for every $Y\subseteq K\mathbb{A}^n$,

(2) $T\subseteq I\big(V(T)\big)$ for every ideal $T$ of $K\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right]$,

(3) If $Y_1,Y_2\subseteq K\mathbb{A}^n$ are such that $Y_1\subseteq Y_2$, then $I\left(Y_1\right)\supseteq I\left(Y_2\right)$,

(4) If $T_1,T_2$ are ideals of $K\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right]$ such that $T_1\subseteq T_2$, then $V\left(T_1\right)\supseteq V\left(T_2\right)$, and

(5) For any ideal $T$ of $K\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right]$, $T\subseteq \sqrt{T}$.

From (2), as $I(X)$ is an ideal of $K\left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right]$, we have $I(X)\subseteq I\Big(V\big(I(X)\big)\Big)$.  From (1), we have $X\subseteq V\big(I(X)\big)$, which means $I(X)\supseteq I\Big(V\big(I(X)\big)\Big)$, due to (3).

Similarly, by (1), as $V(S)\subseteq K\mathbb{A}^n$, we get $V(S)\subseteq V\Big(I\big(V(S)\big)\Big)$.  From (2), $S\subseteq I\big(V(S)\big)$, which leads to $V(S)\supseteq V\Big(I\big(V(S)\big)\Big)$, where (4) is applied.

Now, to show $I(X)=\sqrt{I(X)}$, we have $I(X)\subseteq \sqrt{I(X)}$ from (5).  Suppose $f\in\sqrt{I(X)}$.  Then, $f^k \in I(X)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  That is, for all $p \in X$, $\big(f(p)\big)^k=0_K$, but, as $K$ is an integral ring, $f(p)=0_K$.  Therefore, $f\in I(X)$, or $\sqrt{I(X)}\subseteq I(X)$, as required.

To show that $V(S)=V\left(\sqrt{S}\right)$, we note from (5) that $S\subseteq \sqrt{S}$, which leads to $V\left(\sqrt{S}\right)\subseteq V(S)$, by (4).  Suppose that $p \in V\left(S\right)$.  Then, for $f\in \sqrt{S}$, we have $f^k\in S$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  Consequently, $\big(f(p)\big)^k=0_K$, or $f(p)=0_K$, since $K$ is an integral ring.  Ergo, $p \in V\left(\sqrt{S}\right)$.  Thus, $V(S)\subseteq V\left(\sqrt{S}\right)$, as desired.

If $K$ is a non-integral commutative ring, we only have $\sqrt{I(X)}\supseteq I(X)=I\Big(V\big(I(X)\big)\Big)$ and that $V\big(\sqrt{S}\big)\subseteq V(S)=V\Big(I\big(V(S)\big)\Big)$.  For example, if $K:=\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, we can take $n:=1$, $X:=2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, and $S:=\left(4x_1\right)$.  In this case, $I(X)=\left(4x_1,2x_1+x_1^2,2x_1^2,x_1^3\right)$, whereas $\sqrt{I(X)}=\left(2,x_1\right) \supsetneq I(X)$.  Also, we have $\sqrt{S}=\left(2\right)$, so $V(S)=2\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, but $V\left(\sqrt{S}\right)= 8\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z} \subsetneq V(S)$.

Comment: I asked this for a friend: He was having trouble with his internet connection and sent me the question via SMS. As you may have noticed, this is far beyond the level of my habitual questions. He said that your answer is satisfactory and told me to accept it.

Comment: This answer is not satisfactory for reasons I outlined in a comment above:  the field $K$ should not be assumed algebraically closed and the Nullstellensatz should not be invoked. (I didn't downvote though).

Comment: Well, Voyska is the OP, and he accepted the answer.  So, I guess that he just forgot to mention that $K$ is algebraically closed.  Anyway, I still think that the claim holds even if $K$ is not algebraically closed, or even if $K$ is a commutative integral ring.  I just haven't found a good proof yet.  (Frankly, I don't care if you would downvote my comment.)